# Need to have a GMap without initializing to a specific location

Tags: javascript, google-maps, jquery-location-picker

I am trying to implement a google map that is bound to an input field.

But i need the input field not to have an initial value, and the map to be initially set to a certain city.
Is that possible?
the input field has id "gmap-address".

```
<div class="section">
    <input name="gmap-address" class="form-control" type="text" id="gmap-address" style="font-size:2em;height:3em;"/>
</div>

<input name="gmap-lat" type="text" id="gmap-lat"/>
<input name="gmap-long" type="text" id="gmap-long"/>
<input name="us9-city" type="text" id="us9-city"/>
<input name="us9-state" type="text" id="us9-state"/>
<input name="us9-zip" type="text" id="us9-zip"/>
<input name="us9-street1" type="text" id="us9-street1"/>
<div id="gmap" style="width: 60%; height: 500px; margin:0 auto; padding-top:5%;"></div>

<script>
    function init(lat, long){
        jQuery('#gmap').locationpicker({
            location: {
                latitude: lat,
                longitude: long
            },
            radius: 300,
            onchanged: function (currentLocation, radius, isMarkerDropped) {
                var addressComponents = jQuery(this).locationpicker('map').location.addressComponents;
                updateControls(addressComponents);
            },
            oninitialized: function(component) {
                var addressComponents = jQuery(component).locationpicker('map').location.addressComponents;
                updateControls(addressComponents);
            },
            inputBinding: {
                latitudeInput: jQuery('#gmap-lat'),
                longitudeInput: jQuery('#gmap-long'),
                locationNameInput: jQuery('#gmap-address')
            },
            markerInCenter: true,
            enableAutocomplete: true,
            addressFormat: 'postal_code',
            scrollwheel: false
        });
    }
    function updateControls(addressComponents){
        jQuery('#us9-street1').val(addressComponents.addressLine1);
        jQuery('#us9-city').val(addressComponents.city);
        jQuery('#us9-state').val(addressComponents.district);
        jQuery('#us9-zip').val(addressComponents.postalCode);
        jQuery('#us9-country').val(addressComponents.country);
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your code, the input field does not have any value initially.

As for getting the map to initially be set to a certain city: You can do this when you initiate the map like so:

```
function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
      zoom: 8
    });
  }
```

For specifying the center of the map, you will need to use latitude,longitude coordinates. If you really need to use the name of a city, you can do so by first using the Geocoding API to geocode the city, then you can set the center of the map to the coordinates returned by the geocoder. I have demonstrated how this can be done in the following JSFiddle using Houston, TX as the city the map is initially set to:

https://jsfiddle.net/3qoub0nv/1/

I hope this helps!